# Can't get paddle to move left and right on keydown

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, game-physics

I'm trying to get the paddle to move left and right, and it simply wont. I've double checked all my code. No errors, and still can't seem to resolve it. I'm sure it's something silly, but any guidance would be appreciated :) I am following the guide on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript/Paddle_and_keyboard_controls), but to no avail. Thanks in advance for the help!

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="break.css">
    <title>Brick Breaker | RGL</title>
</head>
<body>
        <canvas id="brickCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <script src="break.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#brickCanvas{
    background: orange;
}
```

**JS**

```
//initializing canvas
    var canvas = document.getElementById('brickCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//beginning ball position
    var x = canvas.width/2;
    var y = canvas.height-30;

//Paddle characteristics
    const PADDLE_HEIGHT = 10;
    const PADDLE_WIDTH = 75;
    var paddleX = (canvas.width-PADDLE_WIDTH)/2;

// Ball characteristics
    var ballRadius = 10;
// dx = ball speed on x-axis, dy = ball speed on y-axis.
    var xSpeed = 2;
    var ySpeed = -2;

// Booleans checking to see if an arrow is clicked
    var rightArrowPressed = false;
    var leftArrowPressed = false;


// Setting up ball color/size
    function drawBall(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#eee";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

//Drawing paddle
    function drawPaddle(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height-PADDLE_HEIGHT, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT);
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

/*
 Allows the ball to move by updating every 10ms, and clears the previously drawn
 ball at the beginning of the function.
 */
    function draw(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
        drawBall();
        drawPaddle()
    /*
     Both if's check for bounce off of ceiling, floor, or wall.
     I am subtracting half the radius(5) from each because it gives the ball a
     nicer touch off of the sides by barely touching instead of going
     into the side.
     */

        if(y + ySpeed > canvas.height-5 || y + ySpeed < 5 ){
            ySpeed = -ySpeed;
        }

        if(x + xSpeed > canvas.height-5|| x + xSpeed < 5){
            xSpeed = -xSpeed;
        }

        //Checking for keyup/keydown to move paddle
        if(rightArrowPressed && paddleX < canvas.width-PADDLE_WIDTH){
            paddleX = paddleX + 5;
        }
        else if(leftArrowPressed && paddleX > 0){
            paddleX = paddleX - 5;
        }

        x = x + xSpeed;
        y = y + ySpeed;
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownCheck, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpCheck, false);

//Checking for keycodes, and setting booleans based on keyup/keydown

function keyDownCheck(e){
    if(e.keycode === 39){
        rightArrowPressed = true;
    }
    else if(e.keycode === 37){
        leftArrowPressed = true;
    }
}

function keyUpCheck(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 39){
        rightArrowPressed = false;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode === 37) {
        leftArrowPressed = false;
    }
}

setInterval(draw,10);
```

Comment: I believe that you are "fighting" yourself having both `keyUp` and `keyDown` handlers. As you press and release a key, both of those are called, and you are setting true first and then immediately false every time. I would try to comment-out the `document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpCheck, false);` line and see what happens. However, you'll need to reset the `*ArrowPressed` variables back to false inside the conditions where those are checked in the `draw()` function.

Comment: @PaulT this did not seem to resolve the issue. I'm not quite sure what is syntactically wrong. However, I see no overburdening when having 2 event listeners on key up and key down.

Comment: Ok, I'll try your code and test a trial run.

Comment: The changes that I mentioned previously worked for me, however, there is another modification needed:  change both `e.keycode` condition checks to `e.keyCode` inside the `keyDownCheck` handler. So, the changes work without needing a keyup handler as you can verify after a test run.

Comment: Typo you have `keycode` in the down handler, should be `keyCode` that will fix the problems. BTW `keyCode` is deprecated and should not be used, use  use `event.code`. Go to MDN to get details

Comment: @Blindman67 Awesome eye. I'm not sure how I didn't notice that, but I'm also unsure as to why I didn't get an error thrown. I appreciate the help!